# Share one monitor and input devices (mouse & keyborad) between two different computers

Tags: keyboard, display, mouse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to share a monitor and the input devices (keyboard & mouse) between two different machines?

For the monitor case, I believe the answer could be straightforward: connect two different input cables, attach a cable to each of the machines, switch between input sources when necessary. However in this case switching between sources manually (by using the buttons on the monitor panel) is really inconvenient. Can this be done via software / keyboard shortcut?

When it comes to the input devices (keyboard & mouse) how to share one pair of devices on multiple machines? Moreover, what if the machines use different OSs?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for a keyboard, video and mouse ([KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch)) switch.

Comment: besides that I would like to have the same functionality via software and not with a specific hardware device

Comment: In that ase you robably want some sort of Remote desktop